# Put text into variable with variables and execute after

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have a command I build using variables which sometimes, they have `"` or `'`. I would like to save a text into a variable without worry about quotes.

Looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346499/bash-put-text-into-a-variable-without-needing-to-escape-characters) was thinking on something like that:

```
ESCAPE_CHAR="${1-\"}"
DELIMITER="${2:-,}"
IFS='' read -r -d '' var <<'EOF'
gunzup -cd ${FILE} | sed -E 's/(${ESCAPE_CHAR}([^${ESCAPE_CHAR}]*)${ESCAPE_CHAR})?${DELIMITER}/\2\t/g'
EOF
split -C 64M -d -a 3 | gzip > $FILE.gz' <(eval "${val}") split/files_
```

What basically happens here is that I convert gzip csv file into tsv.
The problem with this code is that the variables inside the EOD aren't translated into their values. Maybe also the `eval` won't work as it surrounding `val` with quotes, but that remain to be seen.

Comment: You have quoted the here-document, so no wonder the variables are not expanding. It's however unclear to me why you try to do this via a here-document that you `read` and then run `eval` on rather than directly.  It seems a bit awkward. Also, it would probably be easier to use `var=$(cat <<END ... )` rather than `read`.

Comment: I will accept any answer that does what I need. the `eval "$val"` is basically part of bug script. I build the `val` command dynamically based of different variables. Then I execute it as part of bigger command. I edited the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda var=$(cat <<END ... ) did the trick!

Comment: As a starting point read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues that come out of that.

Comment: Use a function instead of a string.